# Performance tuning : alternative to the Do loop

Tags: performance-tuning

I wonder if anyone could help me to improve the following code. I used the Do loop, which is not recommended by MMA. What I need is the final value of 'fB' after looping over `arrB`. I think maybe I should use `Fold`, but I cannot think of any good way. Please note that both `arrA` and `arrB` are lists containing `6` real numbers. `s` is also a real number. The code is as follows.

```
    fB=0;
    pre=s^(-2);
    Do[
        argu=arrB[[i]]*s^2;
        Which[
                argu<.1, fB=fB+arrA[[i]]*arrB[[i]]*(1-.5*argu),
                argu>20, fB=fB+arrA[[i]]*pre,
                argu>=.1 && argu<=20,fB=fB+arrA[[i]]*(1-Exp[-argu])*pre
        ]
    ,{i,6}];
    fB;
```

I'd also like to know is `Piecewise` faster than `Which` in general? Thanks.

Comment: Please include the definition of `arrA` and `arrB` and `s` in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by assuming `arrA`, `arrB` and `s` are some random real numbers:

```
s = RandomReal[];
arrA = RandomReal[1, 6];
arrB = RandomReal[1, 6];
```

Then a function to be used with `Fold` can be formulated as follows:

```
Clear[f]

f[fB_, {a_, b_}] := With[
  {argu = b*s^2, pre = s^(-2)},
  Piecewise[{
    {fB + a*b*(1 - .5*argu), argu < .1},
    {fB + a*pre, argu > 20},
    {fB + a*(1 - Exp[-argu])*pre, argu >= .1 && argu <= 20}
    }]]
```

Note several keys here:

1. initial value `fB` as the first argument in `f`;
2. `{a, b}` are the `Fold`-ed extra values.

Now we can use `Fold` to simply your code:

```
Fold[f, 0, Transpose[{arrA, arrB}]]
```

Comment: This solution is even slower than the original for large lists, mainly because `f` is defined based on pattern matching, which stops `Fold` from auto-compiling.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my attempt by casting Boolean arithmetic to integer arithmetic and using vectorization:

The lists in the OP are a bit too short in order to obtain relyable timing results, so I enlarged them.

```
n = 100000;
s = .5;
pre = s^(-2);
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
B = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];

First@ RepeatedTiming[
 fB = 0;
 Do[
  argu = B[[i]]*s^2;
  fB += Which[
    argu < .1,
    A[[i]]*B[[i]]*(1 - .5*argu),
    argu > 20,
    A[[i]]*pre,
    argu >= .1 && argu <= 20,
    A[[i]]*(1 - Exp[-argu])*pre
    ],
  {i, Lenght[A]}];
 fB
 ]
```

> 0.33

Here is my approach:

```
First@ RepeatedTiming[
 argu = B s^2;
 b1 = N@UnitStep[argu - 0.1];(*argu\[GreaterEqual].1*)
 b2 = N@UnitStep[argu - (1. + $MachineEpsilon) 20];(*argu>20*)
 fB2 = A.Plus[
    Subtract[1., b1] Subtract[1., .5*argu] B,
    b2 pre,
    b1 Subtract[1., b2] Subtract[1., Exp[-argu]] pre
    ]
 ]
```

> 0.0048

So this is almost 70 times faster.

Checking accuracy:

```
Abs[fB - fB2]
```

> 3.41061*10^-13

Answer (score 1):

With your definitions for the values of `s` and `arrA` and `arrB` try this version using `Fold`

```
pre=s^-2;
fun[fB_,{aA_,aB_}]:=fB+
  Which[
           aB*s^2<.1, aA*aB*(1-.5*aB*s^2),
           aB*s^2>20, aA*pre,
           .1<=aB*s^2<=20,aA*(1-Exp[-aB*s^2])*pre
    ];
Fold[fun,0,Transpose[{arrA,arrB}]]
```

Test this carefully to see if it correctly calculates your result with all variations of your input data.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = RandomReal[];
arrA = RandomReal[1, 6];
arrB = RandomReal[1, 6];
pre = s^(-2);

Module[{arrA, arrB, argu}, 
 func = Compile @@ {{#, _Real, 1} & /@ {arrA, arrB}, 
    Which[argu < .1, arrA arrB (1 - .5 argu), argu > 20, arrA pre, True, 
        arrA (1 - Exp[-argu]) pre] /. argu -> arrB s^2 // PiecewiseExpand // 
     Simplify`PWToUnitStep}]

fB = func[arrA, arrB] // Total
```

Or

```
cf = Compile[{{arrA, _Real, 1}, {arrB, _Real, 1}, s}, Module[{fB = 0.,
    pre = s^(-2), argu},
   Do[argu = arrB[[i]]*s^2;
    Which[argu < .1, fB = fB + arrA[[i]]*arrB[[i]]*(1 - .5*argu), argu > 20, 
     fB = fB + arrA[[i]]*pre, argu >= .1 && argu <= 20, 
     fB = fB + arrA[[i]]*(1 - Exp[-argu])*pre], {i, Length@arrA}];
   fB], CompilationTarget -> C, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

cf[arrA, arrB, s] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Remember to remove `CompilationTarget -> C` if you don't have a C compiler installed.