# Optimal way to evaluate a function over many points

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, associations, map

This piggy-backs on my previous question: [Parameter space search routine is too fast?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235636/parameter-space-search-routine-is-too-fast)

I am looking for a fast way to evaluate a symbolic list over many points. So lets say I have a list of symbolic expressions like

```
ListA={a*b*c>0, a*b*(c+1)>0, a*b*(c-1)>0, etc.}
```

and a list of tuples of the form

```
ListB={{1,1,1}, {1,1,2}, {1,2,1}, {1,2,2}< etc.}
```

and I want to evaluate ListA over each tuple of ListB like

```
ListA/.Thread[{a,b,c} -> ListB[[1]]]
ListA /.Thread[{a,b,c} -> ListB[[2]]]
```

Now, my listA can have upwards of tens of thousands points and each expression can be over a hundred lines. My ListB can also be ginormous, like upwards of tens of millions of points, but each tuple only has ~5 elements and I've chunked it into sizes of roughly 100-1000 tuples. My question is then what would be the best way to quickly perform this type of replacements/association?

My first attempt used `ParallelMap` but this took ages still. Then I looked into `Associations` and this cut the time down but each replacement of an element of ListB still takes like 1.5 - 2 seconds, which I need to cut down considerably. Here is a MWE for reference:

```
func = (-2^(1 - px) (-1 + px) px Coth[
       rx sx]^2 (-2 sx y Sech[sx (-rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
        2 sx y Sech[sx (rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2)^2 (Coth[
         rx sx] (-Tanh[sx (-rx + x^2 + y^2)] + 
          Tanh[sx (rx + x^2 + y^2)]))^(-2 + px) - 
    2^(1 - px) px Coth[
      rx sx] (Coth[
         rx sx] (-Tanh[sx (-rx + x^2 + y^2)] + 
          Tanh[sx (rx + x^2 + y^2)]))^(-1 + 
        px) (-2 sx Sech[sx (-rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       2 sx Sech[sx (rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       8 sx^2 y^2 Sech[sx (-rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         sx (-rx + x^2 + y^2)] - 
       8 sx^2 y^2 Sech[sx (rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         sx (rx + x^2 + y^2)]) + 
    2^-px (-1 + px) px Coth[
       rx sx]^2 (-2 sx y Sech[sx (-R - rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
        2 sx y Sech[sx (-R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2)^2 (Coth[
         rx sx] (-Tanh[sx (-R - rx + x^2 + y^2)] + 
          Tanh[sx (-R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]))^(-2 + px) + 
    2^-px px Coth[
      rx sx] (Coth[
         rx sx] (-Tanh[sx (-R - rx + x^2 + y^2)] + 
          Tanh[sx (-R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]))^(-1 + 
        px) (-2 sx Sech[sx (-R - rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       2 sx Sech[sx (-R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       8 sx^2 y^2 Sech[sx (-R - rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         sx (-R - rx + x^2 + y^2)] - 
       8 sx^2 y^2 Sech[sx (-R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         sx (-R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]) + 
    2^-px (-1 + px) px Coth[
       rx sx]^2 (-2 sx y Sech[sx (R - rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
        2 sx y Sech[sx (R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2)^2 (Coth[
         rx sx] (-Tanh[sx (R - rx + x^2 + y^2)] + 
          Tanh[sx (R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]))^(-2 + px) + 
    2^-px px Coth[
      rx sx] (Coth[
         rx sx] (-Tanh[sx (R - rx + x^2 + y^2)] + 
          Tanh[sx (R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]))^(-1 + 
        px) (-2 sx Sech[sx (R - rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       2 sx Sech[sx (R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 + 
       8 sx^2 y^2 Sech[sx (R - rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         sx (R - rx + x^2 + y^2)] - 
       8 sx^2 y^2 Sech[sx (R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]^2 Tanh[
         sx (R + rx + x^2 + y^2)]));

parameters = {px, pz, R, rx, rz, sx, sz}
variables = {x, y, z}

Quantifier[coords_, params_] := 
 Function[Evaluate@Join[variables, parameters], Evaluate@(func > 0)][
  Sequence @@ Join[coords, params]]

SpaceA = Tuples[Range[-2, 2, 0.2], 3];

ListA = Quantifier[#1, parameters] & /@ SpaceA;
ListB = Tuples[Range[1, 4, 0.4], 7];
(*ListB contains~2 million elements*)
```

Now, evaluating `ListA` over `ListB` would proceed like

```
(AllTrue[ListA /. Thread[parameters -> #], TrueQ]) & /@ ListB
(*Careful running this, it will probably take a few months :( *)
```

My problem is that even a single association like

```
ListA/.Thread[parameters->{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}]
```

takes about 2 seconds. So repeating this over a list of ~2 million points would take a century.

Would a compiled function be useful? I dont have much experience using the compile functionality so I'm wondering if it would be advantageous to explore that.
I appreciate any insight!

## Update

Thanks to @flinty suggestion, using  `With` seems to speed up the assignment considerably. Heres a short timing experiment:

Here, `QuantifieroverSpace` corresponds to `ListA` in the MWE above.

```
ClearAll[\[Epsilon], px, pz, R, rx, rz, sx, sz]
ByteCount[QuantifieroverSpace]

With[{\[Epsilon] = 2, px = 1, pz = 5, R = 1, rx = 2, rz = 2, sx = 2, 
   sz = 2},
  Evaluate@AllTrue[QuantifieroverSpace, TrueQ]] // Timing

AllTrue[QuantifieroverSpace /. 
   Thread[{\[Epsilon], px, pz, R, rx, rz, sx, sz} -> {2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 
      2, 2, 2}], TrueQ] // Timing

(*126992696*)
(*{0.000026, False}*)

(*{2.08846, False}*)
```

So using `With` instead of `ReplaceAll` is many orders of magnitude faster, which is interesting. I will implement this in my search routine and see how much it improves it.

## Update 2

So my next issue is that I need the first argument of `With` to be modular to the number of arguments, i.e. it needs to be able to take in either a 3 variable set like {a=1, b=1,c=1} or a different number like {a=1}. My first though would be to do something like

```
With[
     {Thread[SymbolList = ArrayofValues]}, 
     ...
     ]
```

but mathematica is assigning the values in `ArrayofValues` to the symbols in `SymbolList` so that the variable `a` for example has value 1. I then tried

```
init = MapThread[HoldForm[#1=#2]&, {SymbolList, ArrayofValues}];
With[
     Evaluate@ReleaseHold[init],
     ...
     ]
```

but this does the same thing, assigning the values to the symbols. Interestingly, mathematica still executes the `with` expression using the values in the first argument, but its assigning the value to the symbol still, which would slow down the execution of my search routine if I wanted to undo the assignment. I need to somehow halt the `Set`ing assignment but still maintain the form `a=1` in a way dynamic to the number of variables.

## Update 3

Well upon further inspection, I figured out why `With` appears to be so much faster. Its because its not actually subsituting the values of the first argument into the expression. For example,

```
a = {l, s};
With[{l = 3, s = 12},
  Print[Evaluate[a]]
  ];

(*{l,s}*)
```

So I guess I'm back at square one trying to find a faster way to assign values to parameters inside a big symbolic array.

Comment: Have you tried `With[{a = 3, b = 4, c = 1}, Evaluate[thelist]]` ? I'm not sure it will be any faster though.

Comment: Wow, actually for my inital test, ```With``` seems to be considerably faster. I didnt expect that. I'll update my post with a short test. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: What would be a good way to thread the parameter values in the first argument of ```With```? I tried ```With[Evaluate@Thread[{a,b,c}={1,2,3}], ...]``` but that returns ```With::lvws: Variable 2 in local variable specification {2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2} requires a value.```. The variables dont have any assignment before evaluating the ```With```. I need to basically map the ```With``` over the ```ListB```

Comment: I've never used it this way but it's possible apparently: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204117/72682 . The variable spec in the with needs to be held.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I took a look and im still having issues with it. I need to be able to basically input a varying number of parameters since my program is supposed to be modular to the number of parameters, which is why I'm trying to use ```Thread``` so that I could do something like ```With[ Thread[parameters = Listb[[i]]], ...]```. I tried using the ```OwnValue``` approach, but that fails with the same above error message. The issue is ```Set``` is assigning the values of ```ListB[[i]]``` to the symbol used in the parameter. I need to be able to ```Hold``` the ```set``` somehow

Comment: The usual approach to evaluating inequalities is to use `UnitStep[a - b]`, which codes `a>=b`/`a<b` as 1/0, and to evaluate over packed arrays.  [A similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97083/) and some answers related to this approach: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201794
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3500

Comment: Have you tried using an actual function? Define `ListA[a_, b_, c_] = {a*b*c > 0, a*b*(c + 1) > 0, a*b*(c - 1) > 0}` and `ListB = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}`, and then compute `ListA @@@ ListB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, but...

Your function is pretty complicated, and speeding that up is probably more important than how you feed values to it. [`Compile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) is your friend here.

```
cfunc = Compile @@ {Join[variables, parameters], func, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}}

RepeatedTiming[AllTrue[cfunc @@ Join[SpaceA // Transpose, ListB[[1]]], Positive]]
{0.0051, False}
```

At 5ms for a single row of `ListB`, it's still going to take a long time, though it's getting more realistic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried to implement a compiled function with varying success, but I'll try your code and see how it goes

Comment: Wow, that works beautifully. With a diffeerent function (only an analytic function with no hyperbolic trigs), I get roughly 0.0008 seconds for execution. So ```Listable``` allows the function to take in a list of parameters, and then ```Transpose``` changes the list of 3-tuples to a 3 element nested list of the ranges of each element of the 3-tuples? That makes sense with using the ```listable``` attribute. Thank for the great suggestion! That will speed up my search routine considerably

Comment: This actually solves my specific problem, so i'll mark it as such. Perhaps theres still a better way to solve the problem of my original post, but i'm satisfied! Thanks again.